# How to get a dark ActionBarSherlock theme?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using android `Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar` on my application and it gets me a light theme. Is there any way to get a dark theme to my application?

```
<activity
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar" >
```

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I remember dark theme is default theme for actionbarsherlock, just use

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

or

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
```

if action bar is no need

Answer (score 3):

Try to create style and then use it

```
<style name="ActionBarHomeItem" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

---

```
<activity
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarHomeItem" >
```

Comment: There is no predefined Theme called `Theme.Sherlock.Dark`. It's just `Theme.Sherlock`.